# Drupal 7 Form API, Checkboxes with key -> value from database

Tags: 7, forms

I'm working on a custom module and I'm adding a form that uses checkboxes.  All is fine with using code like:

$form['tags'] = array(
   '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#options' => array(
      88 => 'option1',
      100 => 'option 2',
      79 => 'etc'
    ),
   '#title' => t('Tag this project as...'),
  );

The problem comes from the fact that I'd like to pull the key and value from the database (a specific taxonomy).  I do not want to use an autocomplete, I want to use checkboxes.

Specifically, how do I get the results from the database and format into a proper array for the options array?  Also, on the edit version of the form I'm creating, how do I show items that have been "checked" based on their value?

All of the examples I've seen are extremely basic and never show how to do this from a database call.  Thanks for reading/answering

Answer (score 1):

To populate your options array with data from table `my_table`, with value keys from column `value` and text from column `atext`, you can use:

```
$options = array();
$result = db_select('my_table', 'mt')
            ->fields('mt', array('value', 'atext'))
            ->execute();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $options[$row->value] = $row->atext;
}
```

To get taxonomy terms, you could use the code above to query `tid` and `name` from the `taxonomy_term_data` table (plus add a `condition()` for the vocabulary id), but for this specific usage you'd better to use the right API:

```
$options = array();
// Get term tree for vocabulary which id is in $vid.
$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  $options[$term->tid] = $term->name;
}
```

Just do not forget that vocabularies are tree structures. See [the documentation for the `taxonomy_get_tree()` API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7) to know how to limit the terms you want to get from a vocabulary wrt starting term and tree depth.

Comment: Thanks much for the great explanation!  Very helpful.  Sometimes it's very hard to know where to look in the documentation and for which api.